# How to check whether rows of specific columns have the same sign or not in R or Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, r, file-filter

I have spreadsheet with many columns. In that Columns starting with "FC" should have all the rows with same sign.

But below in the table you can see that for the first row "NM_000319" columns "FC_AT1BPABaP1vsAT1NT1" and "FC_AT1BPABaP3vsAT1NT3" have negative sign where as column "FC_AT1BPABaP2vsAT1NT2" is positive.
So, how can I check whether all the three columns having same sign or not.

```
tracking_id FC_AT1BPABaP1vsAT1NT1   FC_AT1BPABaP2vsAT1NT2   FC_AT1BPABaP3vsAT1NT3   
NM_000319   -7514.342949    1.821240463 -2.721908575    
NM_000403   2.831020725 -3.756945063    -251342.1488    
NM_001001560    -21.5329816 4.230898855 4.404446706 
NM_001003818    -738637764.9    1.707630437 1526.524518 
NM_001005290    -7.291187382    1.837827141 -1.993878903    
NM_001009554    -4.321191835    698.4121619 2.260286104 
NM_001009570    6.728377618 346.5860049 -1.877202148    
NM_001014837    -1.950676412    4.527666097 1727.863947 
NM_001018011    12.96256834 -21.85994794    10.07627791 
NM_001020818    5.918729877 43107941834 -5.208946431    
NM_001031848    3.223480013 -3.245050492    -104.259285 
NM_001033578    -9.58E+13   -34519832402    1.614184522 
NM_001037126    1.655300434 2481.777403 -2.389413271    
NM_001039457    3.631318663 1.706726068 6327.407683
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. this formula in Excel:
`=AND(SIGN(B2)=SIGN(C2),SIGN(C2)=SIGN(D2))`

It simply does what you need, checks whether all the three numbers has the same sign.

Comment: Thank you very much @Máté Juhász. It worked but I have a small doubt. In my spread sheet I have 9 columns with name "FC". 3 per group. So, each group should have same sign. In the above way I can get the result for one group. How to do this for all at a time.

Comment: You can simply expand the solution of Máté Juhász: 

=AND(AND(SIGN(B2)=SIGN(C2),SIGN(C2)=SIGN(D2)),AND(SIGN(E2)=SIGN(F2),SIGN(F2)=SIGN(G2)),AND(SIGN(H2)=SIGN(I2),SIGN(I2)=SIGN(J2)))

This compares the sign of the columns by group and then compares if it is true for all groups.

Comment: Yes I did it.It gave me what I want. Thank you very much !!

Comment: If you can't solve it, then please update your question with the exact formula and also describe how exactly it doesn't work (gives error / wrong result...)

Answer (score 0):

In R you can do this:

```
samesign <- function(x) {abs(sum(sign(x)))==length(x)}
apply(mydf,1,samesign)
```

On your data (which I read in to `readindf`) this gives:

```
apply(readindf[,2:4],1,samesign)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```